# how to use collection and other model simultaneously for list type template in marionette + rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, backbone.js, marionette

I hope to know how to use collection and model simultaneously in Backbone Marionette + Rails.

Currently, my template jst.eco has below format.

```
<div class="">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <h2 class="group_title" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="This is for first group checking of user">Group 1</h2>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="group_1_1" value="" <%= @group_checker(@model1.group_1) %>>Lorem ipsum</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="group_1_2" value="" <%= @group_checker(@quotient) %>>Sit dolor amet</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="group_1_3" value="" <%= @group_checker(@quotient) %>>Consectetur odipisicing</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="group_1_4" value="" <%= @group_checker(@quotient) %>>Elit sed do ejusmod</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="group_1_5" value="" <%= @group_checker(@quotient) %>>Tempor incididunt ut labore</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <h2 class="group_title" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="This is for 2nd group checking of user">Group 2</h2>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="group_2_1" value="" <%= @group_checker(@model1.group_2) %>>Et dolore magna aliquo.</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="group_2_2" value="" <%= @group_checker(@quotient) %>>Ut enim ad minim veniam</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="group_2_3" value="" <%= @group_checker(@quotient) %>>Quis nostrud exercitation</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <h2 class="group_title" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="This is for 3rd group checking of user">Group 3</h2>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="group_3_1" value="" <%= @group_checker(@model1.group_3) %>>ut aliquip</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="group_3_2" value="" <%= @group_checker(@quotient) %>>ex ea commodo</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="group_3_3" value="" <%= @group_checker(@quotient) %>>consequat</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <h2 class="group_title" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="This is for other group checking of user">Others</h2>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="group_4_1" value="" <%= @group_checker(@model1.group_4) %>>Duis aute irure</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="group_4_2" value="" <%= @group_checker(@quotient) %>>dolor in reprehenderit</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="group_4_3" value="" <%= @group_checker(@quotient) %>>in voluptate</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="group_4_4" value="" <%= @group_checker(@quotient) %>>velit esse</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="group_4_5" value="" <%= @group_checker(@quotient) %>>cilium dol</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my View for this template is below.

```
class Step1.Fields extends App.Views.ItemView
    template: "wizard/edit_fields"

    serializeData: ->
        {
            model1: @model.toJSON()  # record model
            model2: @options.model2.toJSON() # tabs collection planned
        }

    form:
        focusFirstInput: false

    templateHelpers: ->
        {

            group_checker: (value) ->
                @quotient = Math.floor value/2 
                remainder = value % 2
                return "checked" if remainder == 1
                ""
        }
```

The result of this template seems as this. 
[image]

And I planned to replace the repetitive code, so I've created tabs collection that holds labels of checkboxes such as "lorem ipsum", "dolor sit amet".

The tab model format is as below.

> group_id: 1, id: 1, order_in_group: 1, title: "Lorem ipsum"

And also there is a record model that holds group info to decide the checkboxes status totally.

Please notice it contains group info as this json format.

> group_1 => 25, group_2 => 30, group_3 => 35, group_4 => 27

So the tabs collection is charged to checkbox labels' display and record model is responsible to checkbox statuses' set.

And please notice also because of the style reason, it's not a simple repetition, but contains col-sm-x seperation with 2 groups per column.

So, I am in real dilemma.

It seems that it's not eligible CollectionView of course, so I thought about using CompositeView in Marionette, but I couldn't imagine how to handle tabs collection and record model simultaneously to write the template with the same as previous one.

Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

CompositeView is your answer here, as you were already partially on track to doing so.

Your collection/model only pertain to the data, so that will be irrelevant. As long as your item view contains all of the UI and proper template for each individual model in the collection, and you have a template for the collection, you can render in multiple regions specified in the CompositeView. Set `childView` to the class of your model view, and `childViewContainer` to the element you want to render inside of, in this case it looks as though a `div.form-class` is the element type housing your child views / models being displayed.

Comment: It seems a bit vague.
Can you please give me code example or detail to solve my problem?

Comment: My answer pertains to the specificities of the problem, your code is written in what I believe is CoffeeScript or TypeScript perhaps? I have not used either of those before, so I can neither write an example in them or translate your code sufficiently to my answer. I reference and highlight the exact properties that need set to do what you want done.